# Implementation of inherited class' method (param=pointer to parent) in child class (param=pointer to child)

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, parameters, implementation

Say if I have an interface with virtual methods, but one of the arguments are:

```
virtual void Delete(ParentClass *parentClass) = 0;
```

If I later implement this in child class

```
void Delete(ChildClass *childClass)
{
};
```

...why doesn't this work as an implementation?

Comment: C++ doesn't supports parameter covariance in virtual function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the function prototype differs (one uses `ParentClass` and the other `ChildClass`) they are *not* the same functions. Instead the one with the `ChildClass` argument is overloading and not overriding the `Delete` function.

Comment: But since it's an interface, it's not implemented before Child implements it and since Child has the same properties of ParentClass - why would this be a problem and is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Could I override parentclasses method: virtual void Delete() = 0; with void Delete(ChildClass *childClass);?

Comment: @Deukalion No, as then the parent method would have no arguments and the child method an argument, and they still would be different.

Comment: The method in derived class ***Hides*** method in Base class.This is ***Function Hiding*** and not ***Function Overloading***. Function overloading is when several declarations coexist for the same name in the same scope(`C++03 13/1`)

Comment: @Als I still get some of those terms wrong, even though having programmed in C++ for soon 20 years. :)

Comment: That is (*understandbly*)true for all of us :)

Answer (score 0):

**C++03 Standard: 10.3/2**

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` **with the same name and same parameter list as `Base::vf` is declared**, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual an it overrides `Base::vf`.

Note the text in bold.
An derived class function overides a Base class function only and only if it has the same signature as the Base class function with the exception of ***[Co-Variant return types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9feath%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)***. Since your function `Delete()` does not have the same signature in Base Class and Derived class, the derived class function is not overidding the Base class function but what you get is merely ***[Function Hiding](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/hiding-rule.html)***.

**C++03 Standard: 3.3.7/1:**

> A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a nested declarative region or derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Because any type that's accepted as an argument for the base-class function, must also be acceptable by an override of that function. This prevents an error such as:

```
struct BastardClass : ParentClass {} wrong;
Delete(&wrong);
```

which, if dispatched to the override that expects a `ChildClass`, would cause it to interpret the object as the wrong type.

(This is known as *contravariance* - arguments to a function overridden by a *more* specific type must be *no more* specific than those being overridden. For similar reasons, return types must be *covariant* - those specified by a function overridden by a *more* specific type must be *no less* specific.)